# Які мови є найближчими до української мови?

Tags: історія-мови, linguistics

Йдеться про сукупну спорідненість мов за різними факторами: лексика, фонетика, спільність історичного розвитку тощо.

Білоруська мова для мене, наприклад, звучить дуже подібно до української (значно ближче ніж, скажімо, російська чи польська). Неслов'янські мови видаються не дуже схожими на українську, хоча деякі спільні риси теж можна знайти. Також я десь читав, що українська навіть має багато однакових слів із санскритом.

Але чи є якісь науково обґрунтовані дані на цю тему?

Comment: Пов'язані запитання на Linguistics.SE: [Is there a list of mutually intelligible languages?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/is-there-a-list-of-mutually-intelligible-languages) and [Worldwide map or data for linguistic distance?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17400/worldwide-map-or-data-for-linguistic-distance) (щоправда, відповіді також посилаються на роботи проф. Тищенка)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Безумовно, це білоруська. З санскритом стільки ж спільних слів, як і з давньогрецькою, тобто не дуже багато, просто всі ці мови належать до однієї мовної сім’ї, індоєвропейської.

Про ступінь близькости української до инших словʼянських мов є [цікаве відео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Bqdvm4AYAw), де [Костянтин Тищенко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), професор Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка та доктор філології, розповідає про свої дослідження цього питання. [Ще одне відео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HtXo41GCTs) з його лекцією на цю ж тему. Це 45-хвилинні лекції, та раджу подивитися й послухати, дуже цікаві.

**UPD:** Виношу сюди з коментарів посилання на пречудову статтю Костянтина Тищенка [«Правда про походження української мови»](http://i.tyzhden.ua/content/photoalbum/2012/10_12/04/tyshenko/tyshenko.pdf), надруковано в часописі «Тиждень» у 2012 році. У статті викладено все те, про що йдеться в його відеолекціях. Стаття оповідає про місце української мови серед инших слов’янських мов, детально аналізується, до яких саме мов українська найближча.

Comment: Дякую, дуже цікаво! Можливо, є ще якісь опубліковані праці, матеріали досліджень тощо? (можна в електронному вигляді, але текстовому)

Comment: @Maksym - Так одразу й не знайду, це не моя тема, але ось дві великі статті того ж Костянтина Тищенка, це приблизно те саме, про що він каже в тих лекціях, тільки текстом: [«Правда про походження української мови»](https://parafia.org.ua/biblioteka/istoriya-mova/k-tyschenko-pravda-pro-pohodzhennya-ukrajinskoji-movy/) та [«Всеслов'янські складники
української мови»](http://journal.mandrivets.com/images/file/Tyshchenko_2010_3.pdf). Хай назви статтей вас не засмучують, там все по темі вашого питання.

Comment: Ось краще посилання на [«Правда про походження української мови»](http://i.tyzhden.ua/content/photoalbum/2012/10_12/04/tyshenko/tyshenko.pdf), той документ видалено зі Scribd, його не можна там скачати.

Comment: Ось цікава [мапа що створена на основі даних Тищенка](https://alternativetransport.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/34/).

Answer (score 10):

Походження східнослов'янських мов досить добре дослідив Юрій Шевельов.

Його визначні праці в цьому напрямку:

1. A Prehistory of Slavic. The Historical Phonology of Common Slavic. Heidelberg (Carl Winter Univer-sitatsverlag), 1964 і New York (Columbia University Press), 1965. / <sub>переклад відсутній?</sub>
2. A Historical Phonology of the Ukrainian Language. Heidelberg (Carl Winter Universitatsverlag), 1979. / Історична фонологія української мови, Акта, 2002

Основні тези з цих праць зібрані у статті «[Чому общерусский язык, а не вібчоруська мова?](http://documentslide.com/documents/-557205ee497959fc0b8b805b.html)», звідки наступна схема перегрупування первісних говіркових регіонів у три східнослов'янські мови:

[image: Схема перегрупування первісних говіркових регіонів у три східнослов'янські мови]

Позначення на схемі:

НТ — Новгородсько-Тверський регіон,
ПС — Полоцько-Смоленський регіон,
МР — Муромсько-Рязанський регіон,
КП — Києво-Поліський регіон,
ГП — Галицько-Подільський регіон.

Answer (score 3):

З точки зору лексики найближчою до української є білоруська (84% спільної лексики), потім польська (70% спільної лексики), словацька (68% спільної лексики) та на четвертому місці — російська (62% спільної лексики).

Comment: Було б дуже добре якби ви надали джерела цього твердження, дякую.

Comment: думаю, маються на увазі [такі результати](https://elms.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/lexical-distance-among-languages-of-europe/) які посилаються на [Костянтин Тищенко. Метатеорія мовознавства](http://linguist.univ.kiev.ua/museum/book/index.html)